Azure Synapse Deployment Failure with "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
Failure to deploy azure synapse pipelines with below error:
Set-AzSynapsePipeline : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
2024-05-08T08:29:52.7382260Z [31;1m[31;1m+ …   $deploy = Set-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -Name …[0m
2024-05-08T08:29:52.7383016Z [31;1m[31;1m+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2024-05-08T08:29:52.7383393Z [31;1m[31;1m+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzSynapsePipeline], TargetInvocationException[0m
2024-05-08T08:29:52.7383749Z [31;1m[31;1m+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Synapse.SetAzureSynapsePipeline[0m
2024-05-08T08:29:52.8744372Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2024-05-08T08:29:52.9169560Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy synapse pipelines
Powershell Script Used for deployment:
#Pipelines - Raw/pipeline_snapshot_merge 
        $pipeline_snapshot_merge= Get-ChildItem -Path "./pipelines/snapshot/merge"
        Write-Verbose "Adding snapshot merge and get catalog files pipelines to workspace"

        foreach ($pipeline_to_create in $pipeline_snapshot_merge) {
            
            
            try {

                $deploy = Set-AzSynapsePipeline -WorkspaceName $WorkspaceName -Name $pipeline_to_create.BaseName -DefinitionFile $pipeline_to_create

                if ($deploy.AdditionalProperties.count -ne 0) {
                     Write-Host "$($pipeline_to_create.BaseName) failed to deploy"
                     Write-Host "$($deploy.AdditionalProperties.error.message)"
                }
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host "An error occurred while deploying $($pipeline_to_create.BaseName): $($_.Exception.Message)"
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }

Any resolution for the above error

Could you share the deployement code here

Its basically a powershell script that is being used ,updated the question with it

I think issue seems to be from the data in  ./pipelines/snapshot/merge1 file. Could you share this?
